# systemctl restart X causes Connection reset by peer

Tags: systemd, nfs

I have a google compute instance with a startup scrtip that executes
`systemctl restart nfs-kernel-server`, which causes the following errors:

```
Jan 27 14:32:15 nfs startup-script: INFO startup-script: Warning! D-Bus connection terminated. 
Jan 27 14:32:15 nfs startup-script: INFO startup-script: Failed to wait for response: Connection reset by peer
Jan 27 14:32:15 nfs startup-script: INFO startup-script: Return code 1.
```

The service started eventually after 3 minutes..

Is this a timeout issue? Any tips?